# Updating user meta on save post

Tags: user-meta, save-post

I have a custom post type called 'programmes' that details seminar information. Using a form visitors to the site can signup to a specific 'programme', once they have completed the form a new user is created with the following user meta:

- programme_id - the post ID of the 'programme' registered on
- programme_name - the title of the 'programme' registered on
- programme_end_date - the date the 'programme' ends

The 'programme' dates are often changed (due to venue availability etc) after users have already registered, as a result I need to update the programme_end_date user meta field when these changes happen.

I know it's going to be some combination of the `save_post` action along with `update_user_meta` and presumably a loop to check for all the users that have the specific updated 'programme' ID in the programme_id user meta field, but I can get my head round exactly how to do it. Any pointers would be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query all the authors and loop through to update their dates. The below query pulls all users who have a `programme_id` of the current `post_id` and allocates an array of their IDs. You can then loop through to update whatever is necessary:

```
/** Save Custom Metaboxes **/
function save_custom_meta_boxes( $post_id, $post ) {

    /** 
     * Your Testing conditions should go here to ensure
     * That we're in the correct place and actually need to
     * run this query. I suggest checking against post type 
     */

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'meta_key'  => 'programme_id',
        'meta_value'=> $post_id,
        'fields'    => 'ID',
    ) );

    if( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach( $user_query->results as $user_id ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'programme_end_date', $_POST['some_data_here'] );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_meta_boxes', 10, 2 );
```

I kept it as simple as possible and if you have a *ton* of users this may not be optimal.

Comment: I think you understood the question better than I did. :)

Comment: Sorry only just got back round to this. Your answer looks excellent and I can follow the logic, however for some reason $user_id is passing an array of values(!) as opposed to the actual ID, any idea?

Comment: @charliek Whoops! Fixed that. WP_Query puts it's results into a `posts[]` array. Usually it's an array of Post objects ( $post->ID, $post->post_date, etc ) but since we're only returning 1 field (ID) it's returning an array in integers. Anyway, to access this array we need to loop through `$user_query->posts` instead. If this solves you issue please ensure th click the checkmark so future readers know it's solved!.

Comment: This throws the follow errors - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /.../functions.php on line 420
and
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../functions.php:420) in /.../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Comment: Have solved it. We we missing` $user_query->get_results()`

Comment: @charliek Good catch! Updated the answer and was able to test it successfully on my install.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure what your aim is but I can definitely get you on your feet.

So you want to hook into `save_post`, confirm which `post_status` your are targeting, and then update user/post meta as you wish.

I've written this for you, **see the comments** for clarification and adjust it as you please:

```
add_action('save_post', 'wp_220873', 10, 2);

function wp_220873($id, $p) {

    // confirm if post is being published (or whatever post status you're targetting)
    if (
        (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)
        || ($p->post_status !== 'publish')
    ) {
        return;
    }

    // update post meta as you wish
    update_post_meta( $p->ID, 'meta_key', $value );

    // update user meta as you wish
    update_user_meta( $p->post_author, 'meta_key', $value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in the `save_post` hook

```
// search users which have this programme id

$args = array(
    "meta_query" => [
        [
            "key" => "programme_id",
            "value" => $programme_id,
        ]
    ],
);

$wp_user_search = new \WP_User_Query($args);
$items = $wp_user_search->get_results();


foreach ($items as $user) {

    // update end date

    update_user_meta($user->ID, "programme_end_date", $programme_end_date);


}
```